# Array of a Struct C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have made struct and now I need to create an array for the corresponding struct. Could anyone help me how to go about that? I have looked at stuff online and couldn't really understand it, so could anyone give me an example and explanation on how to create an array of a struct.

```
 struct CANDIDATE{

    string candiFN;
    string candiLN;
    int partyID;
    int votes;  

};
```

Comment: Depends on whether the array should have static or dynamic size. And `CANDIDATE` is a bad name for a struct, because it looks like a preprocessor macro.

Comment: Another naming note; when fields are contained inside of a structure or class, there is no need to repeat the name of the structure in the field.  If it was just firstName and lastName, whose first and last name would it be...if not the candidate's?

Answer (score 4):

The same way you make any array. The following makes an array of length 5.

```
CANDIDATE foo [5];
```

Then you can fill it however you'd like

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    CANDIDATE temp("first", "second", 1, 2);
    foo[i] = temp;
}
```

Or

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    CANDIDATE temp;
    temp.candiFN = "first";
    temp.candiLN = "second";
    temp.partyID = 1;
    temp.votes = 2;
    foo[i] = temp;
}
```

Note that in C++ using a `std::vector` introduces more safety and flexibility to most applications.

```
std::vector<CANDIDATE> bar;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    CANDIDATE temp("first", "second", 1, 2);
    bar.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Why would you use this when you have `std::vector` and `std::array` (or `boost::array` for pre-C++11)? Unless you want the OP to learn the evils of raw arrays the hard way.

Comment: Well, they asked for an array, so they got an array! I'll throw a vector in there too for good measure :)

Comment: Unnecessary down-votes by SO users who think that arrays are not part of the C++ language will begin shortly.

Comment: don't use emplace_back as another push_back, its a delegating constructor

Comment: @Cyber: I think many C++ beginners today come from other programming languages, where arrays are rather safe and normal (e.g. Java or even PHP). When they come to C++, when they talk about *arrays*, what they mostly really mean is *the standard way to have a collection of stuff*. And that in C++ is `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
struct CANDIDATE{
    string candiFN;
    string candiLN;
    int partyID;
    int votes;  
}array[5];
//just add an array between } and ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of values

```
CANDIDATE foo[5];
```

or a pointer array

```
CANDIDATE* foo = new CANDIDATE[5];
```

The first goes in the stack, the second in the heap and need manual delete

Anyway consider of use `std::vector`